# Parse period/duration string literal into Period/Duration instance in Java

Tags: java, date, parsing, time

I would like to parse any duration/period string literal (in the format shown in the examples below) into a Period/Duration instance in Java.

By duration/period, I mean an amount of time that contains both date-based and time-based quantities. In Java, `Duration` alone only works for time-based quantities like seconds, minutes, and hours, while `Period` alone only works for date-based quantities like years, months, and days.

The string to parse won't always contain all quantities.

Examples:

- `29 days 23 hours 59 minutes 20 seconds`
- `4 years 10 months 10 seconds`
- `10 days 9 minutes`
- `1 month`

How would I do that, if possible?

Comment: This question is somewhat researched and accounting well for the difference between `Period` and `Duration`. It’s also a very interesting question that could be useful for many readers. Even though we could wish for an account of what a search brought up, I find it unfair to downvote the question.

Answer (score 5):

### Convert your string to ISO 8601 format and parse into PeriodDuration

My idea is to use the `PeriodDuration` class of the ThreeTen Extra project. It combines the `Period` and `Duration` classes that you already mention. A limitation is that its `parse` method only accepts ISO 8601 format, so we need to convert your string into that format first. ISO 8601 format is like `P10DT9M` for 10 days 9 minutes. The `P` is fixed. The `T` marks the beginning of the time-based part if there is one (hours, minutes, seconds) to separate it from the date-based part (years, months, weeks, days). A nice consequence is that we can always tell whether `M` means months or minutes: If `M` comes before `T` or there is no `T`, it means months. If `M` comes after `T`, it means minutes. My first code snippet converts your string to ISO 8601.

```
    String[] examples = {
            "29 days 23 hours 59 minutes 20 seconds", 
            "4 years 10 months 10 seconds",
            "10 days 9 minutes", 
            "1 month" 
    };
    
    for (String pds : examples) {
        // If hours, minutes or seconds are present, put a T before them
        String temp = pds.replaceFirst("(\\d+ *(?:hour|minute|second))", " T $1");
        // Abbreviate all units to 1 letter; remove spaces
        temp = temp.replaceAll("([ymwdhms])[a-z]*", "$1").replace(" ", "");
        // Prepend P
        String iso = "P" + temp;
        System.out.println(iso);
    }
```

Output so far is:

> ```
> P29dT23h59m20s
> P4y10mT10s
> P10dT9m
> P1m
> ```

After this we should be able to parse:

```
        PeriodDuration pd = PeriodDuration.parse(iso);
```

I have not installed ThreeTen Extra, so I have not tried this last line before posting it. The OP reported in a comment that it works like a charm on ThreeTen Extra 1.6.0. The only caveat is that the units have to be in descending order when parsing the string, otherwise it throws a `DateTimeParseException`.

Don’t worry that ISO 8601 format is usually given in upper case and your units are in lower case. The documentation of the `parse` method states:

> The sections have suffixes in ASCII of "Y" for years, "M" for months,
> "W" for weeks, "D" for days, "H" for hours, "M" for minutes, "S" for
> seconds, accepted in upper or lower case.

Edit: With thanks to Arvind Kumar Avinash for the comment, if you need to accept upper case letters too, add the `(?i)` flag expression in your regular expression to enable case-insensitive matching:

```
        temp = temp.replaceAll("(?i)([ymwdhms])[a-z]*", "$1").replace(" ", "");
```

### Links

- [ThreeTen Extra project home](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/)
- [Documentation of `PeriodDuration.parse()`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/PeriodDuration.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence))
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: This is a very good answer. I suggest you use `(?i)` i.e. change the pattern to `(?i)([ymwdhms])[a-z]*` so that it can work in a case-insensitive way. Currently, it will fail for another case e.g. `Month`.

Comment: Also, you can use `(\\d+\\s*(?:hour|minute|second))` because currently `*` seems to be redundant in your pattern.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash We may. Then we’d also need `.replaceAll("\\s", "")` later. There’s plenty of room for adjustment based on the more precise needs of the asker and other readers. I will leave them to the reader until an actual need arises. But please let your comment stand, it may be helpful.

Comment: I did not understand why you would need to use `.replaceAll("\\s", "")` later in that case...you are already using `.replace(" ", "")` which will do this job. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hi, Ole. Thank you for the answer :)

I can confirm that the code you provided works like a charm on ThreeTen Extra 1.6.0. 

The only caveat is that the units have to be in descending order when parsing the string, otherwise it throws a `DateTimeParseException`. But it's nothing that can't be caught and handled by rearranging the string accordingly before it is parsed.

Comment: That might be a bit of a stretch, but in case other users want to use to use their own format instead of the one I showed in the examples, is it possible to define a `DateTimeFormatter` or something similar that can be used to parse the string?

Comment: No, @Marwi, a `DateTimeFormatter` is fine for parsing dates and times but will not work for parsing periods and/or durations. The now “finished” Joda-Time project had a flexible `PeriodFormatter` class that could probably be used. However the regular expression approach I have presented here is very flexible too. I have used it in a number of Stack Overflow answers for parsing `Duration`s from various formats.